# Broadcast Receiver declaration in manifest error on intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an Android app using IntelliJ 12.1.4. When I create a new android component with type receiver the receiver is added to the manifest as

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=" com.example.ACTION_EXAMPLE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but giving an error "class or interface expected". I tried to put the receiver including the package name but I still get the same error. The project compiles successfully but the when a broadcast is sent with the intent filter associated with the receiver the receiver receives nothing.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to define the intent-filter with the receiver

```
       <receiver
        android:name="Your receiver Name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             //your action to perform on broadcast receiver
        </intent-filter>
```

after this in your receiver class you have to check

```
        if(intent(object of intent in onreceive method).equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
         {

          //  action to perform
        }
```

Comment: Its already there, I just didn't put it in the question. I've added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<receiver android:name=".clsBroadcastreceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name= "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Above code use to register receiver in manifest file.

```
<action android:name= "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

Above code must changed according to the broadcast receiver. I use above for triggering a SMS receive event.

Then you have to implement clsBroadcastreceiver by extending BroadcastReceiver

```
public class clsBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Also you need to Override onReceive method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
}
```

What ever you want to do with broadcast receive event, put in onReceive (...) {...}